# Scala: How to sum the mapValues in Map[String, List[(String, Map[Long, Int])]]

Tags: scala

It is a complicated structure for example:

```
val testMap: Map[String, List[(String, Map[Long, Int])]] = Map(
  "test1" ->
    List(
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(2222222222L -> 2))
    )
)
```

How can I sum the values with the same key? I'm expecting the result to be:

```
Map(test1 -> Map(1111111111 -> 8, 2222222222 -> 2))
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
val res = testMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ ++ _))
```

BUT the result I get is:

```
Map(test1 -> Map(1111111111 -> 2, 2222222222 -> 2))
```

1111111111 has the value 2 instead of 8. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear whether the `test1` in the result is from the outer `Map` or the inner `Map`. Can you give an example with different keys in the input to show exactly what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this I know it looks little complicated but I was trying to cover some corner case to make the code more dynamic

```
testMap.mapValues{values =>
      values.groupBy(_._1).flatMap{
        case (_ , values) =>
          values.foldLeft(Map.empty[Long, Int]){
            case (acc, (_, nextMap)) =>
              nextMap.flatMap{
                case (key, value) =>
                  acc.get(key).fold(acc + (key -> value))(intValue => acc + (key -> (value + intValue)))
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need reduce your values in your inner map you can use foldLeft and accumulate result map:

```
def combineInner(mapA: Map[Long, Int], mapB: Map[Long, Int]): Map[Long, Int] = {
  mapA.foldLeft(mapB) {
    case (mapWithSum, (key, value)) =>
      mapWithSum.updated(key, mapWithSum.getOrElse(key, 0) + value)
  }
}

val res = testMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(combineInner))
```

but remember you will lost outer map keys in this way and string values in list (thirst element in list of pairs).

UPDATE:
If you can use **cats** library, you can do more simple just using cats *semigroup* type class:

```
import cats.implicits._
val res = testMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ |+| _))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on your own solution:

```
val testMap: Map[String, List[(String, Map[Long, Int])]] = Map(
  "test1" ->
    List(
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(1111111111L -> 2)),
      ("test1", Map(2222222222L -> 2))
    )
)

val res = testMap.map(t => (t._1, t._2.map(_._2).reduce((map1, map2) => { 
  val combinedMap = map1.map { 
     case (k, v1) => 
        (k, map2.get(k).map(v2 => v1 + v2).getOrElse(v1)) 
  }

  val uniqueKeyFromMap2 = map2.filterNot(t => map1.contains(t._1))

  combinedMap ++ uniqueKeyFromMap2 
})))
```